# Sort an ArrayList in alphabetical order without using java.util.Collections

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, alphabetical

For an assignment I have to sort an ArrayList in alphabetical order and print it without using java.util.Collections, meaning I have to come up with my own algorithm to put it in ABC order. I haven't been able to figure it out on my own and everyone online uses Collections. Any help?

My code is not really needed to answer my question, but nevertheless here it is:

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList <String> word = new ArrayList <String> ();
    System.out.println("Enter the next name:");
    String str = input.nextLine();
    String compared = "STOP";
    while (!compared.equalsIgnoreCase(str))
    {
      String action = str.toLowerCase();
      action = str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
      word.add(action);
      System.out.println("Enter the next name:");
      str = input.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(word);
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So it looks like its time to do some research on sorting algorithms.  I'd suggest having a look at Bubble Sort to start with, while to particular efficient, it's simple to implement

Comment: Two approaches: (1) Think about how you would do this if you were given a bunch of names on a piece of paper and told to sort them.  I think this is best because it's good practice for other times when you'll need to think up your own algorithm.  (2) Look up "Sorting algorithm" in Wikipedia.

Comment: As above wrote, start with an brute force algorithm. And then research better options and implement them. That's a good way to learn I think. Also compare the sped of both algorithms you implemented.

Comment: Google bubble sort and have fun.